# SQL Server return records with different occurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I the following table.

```
SupplierId  AuditId  QuestionId  Answer
3           123      1           abc
3           456      1           abc
3           789      1           abc
```

I want to see where in this table the following happens

```
SupplierId  AuditId  QuestionId  Answer
3           123      1           abc
3           456      1           abc
3           789      1           def
```

I want to know where column `D` deviates. I was thinking of a Window Function like a `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT SupplierId, AuditId, QuestionId, Answer , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SupplierId, AuditId, QuestionId ORDER BY SupplierId) AS numOccurences
FROM Analytics2.Data.Question
ORDER BY SupplierId
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query will give you all those supplier id's who have multiple different Column D values in it

```
    SELECT SupplierId, count(distinct D) 
      AS numOccurences
       FROM Analytics2.Data.Question
           group by SupplierId having 
          count(distinct D) >1
         ORDER BY SupplierId
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the `AuditID` from the Partition By clause:

```
SELECT SupplierId, 
       AuditId, 
       QuestionId, 
       Answer , 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SupplierId,  QuestionId 
                          ORDER BY SupplierId,QuestionId) AS numOccurences
FROM Analytics2.Data.Question
ORDER BY sipplierId
```

If you need to only track the changes then use an Common table expression:

```
WITH CTE_1 AS (
    SELECT SupplierId, 
       AuditId, 
       QuestionId, 
       Answer , 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SupplierId,  QuestionId 
                          ORDER BY SupplierId,QuestionId) AS numOccurences
FROM Analytics2.Data.Question

)SELECT * FROM CTE_1 
 WHERE numOccurences = 1
 ORDER BY sipplierId
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the row (and row number) in your table where the `Answer` field changes:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SupplierId) AS row
    FROM Question)
SELECT cte2.* 
FROM cte cte1
JOIN cte cte2 ON cte2.row = cte1.row + 1 AND cte2.Answer != cte1.Answer
```

Output:

```
SupplierId  AuditId     QuestionId  Answer  row
3           789         1           def     3
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=07074fd96ca71199ed205b4dbcd62231)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what version of SQL Server you use. SQL Server 2012 implemented `LEAD` and `LAG` functions. They are very efficient for this kind of query.

Here is one variant of how to use them. Adjust `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses to match your requirements, which are not clear from the question.

```
WITH 
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        SupplierId, AuditId, QuestionId, Answer
        ,LAG(Answer) OVER (PARTITION BY SupplierId ORDER BY AuditID) AS PrevAnswer
    FROM Analytics2.Data.Question
    ORDER BY SupplierId, AuditID
)
SELECT
    SupplierId, AuditId, QuestionId, Answer
FROM CTE
WHERE
    Answer <> PrevAnswer
;
```